# Angular 4 set setter with (click)

Tags: javascript, angular

I currently have this:

On the .html

```
<input [(ngModel)] = data />
```

and on the .ts file:

```
set data(value) {
  // do something
}
```

Instead of having this:

```
<input [(ngModel)] = data />
```

I want to have a button that with set the data of the setter...

```
<button (click)="set value here"></button>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please check out : https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#how-to-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
<button (click)="data=7"></button>
```

But a better option is to define a method to do it.

Here is an example:

```
<button type="button" (click)="setValue(7)">
```

And then in the component:

```
setValue(value): void {
    this.data = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't the the two -way binding, then you can use [value] attribute:

```
<input [value] = "data" />

<button (click)="data=newData">...</button>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qatfst?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Or refer to the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#how-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

You can use local reference

in your `html`

`<input type="text" #data />`

`<button type="button" (click)="getData(data)">`

and in yout `ts` file

```
getData(data){
    this.data = data.value;
}
```